# Send data by TCP socket and plotting on Gnuplot

Tags: sockets, tcp, pthreads, gnuplot

I'm trying receiving data from a TCP socket using threads. My program works very well, but when I try create an object of a Gnuplot class, the program cannot create a connection. The code that works well is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
float Ax,Ay,Az;
Ax=Ay=Az=0.0;
TCP_Client casa295;

casa295.setPortServer("5502");
casa295.setPortNum("5500");
casa295.setServer("localhost");
casa295.setStartSocket();

while(1)
{
    Ax = casa295.getAx();
    Ay = casa295.getAy();
    Az = casa295.getAz();
    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n",Ax,Ay,Az);
    Ax = 0.0;
    usleep(33333);
}
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

The TCP connection on the linux console give me:

```
Creating TCP socket on port 5502
Successfully connected to socket for output ...
```

By adding this simple line:

```
Gnuplot gp;
```

The socket connection gives this output:

```
Creating TCP socket on port 5502
Could not connect to socket for output ...
```